# How to fetch multiple collections in one view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to fetch multiple collection inside one view. I have Dashboard, where are two tables. One for ship and other for shipday. First I had to fetch only the collection of ship in dashboard. It was done, now I have to fetch collection of shipday also in the same view, which is very challenging at the moment. I hope to get help from you guys. 
This makes two collections messing each others place in view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call  get method for Second Collection from your callback function Success which is handling first collection.

Comment: @KaranPatyal Some practically implemented solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Parse.User.current().get('host').relation('ships').query().collection().fetch().then(collectionFetchSuccess, collectionFetchError);
Parse.User.current().get('host').relation('shipdays').query().collection().fetch().then(collectionFetchSuccess, collectionFetchError);
```

like Karan mentioned in the comment area.You need to call the second collection's fetch in the callback function of first collection's fetch

```
Parse.User.current().get('host').relation('ships').query().collection().fetch({
  success : function(collection){
    shipFetchSuccess(collection)
    Parse.User.current().get('host').relation('shipdays').query().collection().fetch().then(shipdaysFetchSuccess, collectionFetchError)
  },
  error : function(){
    collectionFetchError()
  }
})
```

and You need to edit collectionFetchSuccess too. because it requires both collections eventhough It has only 1 parameter.

```
  var shipdaysFetchSuccess = function(collection) {
      var shipdaysView = new ShipdaysTableView({ collection: collection });
      self.subViews.push(shipdaysView);
      self.$el.find('.shipdays').html(shipdaysView.render().el);
  };

  var shipFetchSuccess = function(collection) {

      var shipsView = new ShipsTableView({ collection: collection });
      self.subViews.push(shipsView);
      self.$el.find('.ships').html(shipsView.render().el);
  };
```